# My port is closed,even after port forwarding

Tags: networking, server, apache2, iptables, firewall

I am running Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and my server is accessible from all the devices connected to my WIFI router (including phones,and laptops).[This is the what is rendered when my server is accessed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biwl6.png)
Now I want to access my server from Internet.

**This is the output of route -n**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
```

**This is the output of ifconfig**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:8d:5c:a5:eb:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5856  bytes 572976 (572.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5856  bytes 572976 (572.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxd03745b828ea: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.39  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2970:d411:fb39:7ff6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:37:45:b8:28:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 388866  bytes 507534243 (507.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2905  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 263147  bytes 67686494 (67.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**This is the output of ufw status**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**This is the output of sudo netstat -tlpn**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      706/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      975/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      938/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2201/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2201/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1045/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      975/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      938/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      2201/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      2201/smbd
```

To make my machine public I need to do port forwarding.For that I would be configuring my WIFI router.
[I did it like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OaDb.png)

[This is my WAN status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cu15.png)

I believed that this should be enough to make my machine public.[I tested it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzLTz.png)It is showing that my port is closed.

Now, I thought of using iptables to do port forwarding.[I followed this tutorial](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables)
and entered the following commands.

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlxd03745b828ea/forwarding 
1
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlxd03745b828ea --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.39:80
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.39 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlxd03745b828ea proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlxd03745b828ea scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlxd03745b828ea proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.39 metric 600
```

Now,I believe that I have tried everything to make my server public.[I again tested my machine accessibility here which shows my failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnQgz.png)

I have contacted my ISP and confirmed that all ports are open.I hope I have explained and substantiated everything I did.It would be great if anyone corrects me and provide me a solution to my problem.
Thanking you

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your ISP provides you with a public and unique IPv4? Nowadays, most ISPs will put you behind CGNAT, unless you pay for the IP!  I presume you can check the IP address obtained by your router by checking the router's WAN status page...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli,I confirmed that they do not provide static ip but not about unique ip.I have edited my question which even shows my WAN info.I do not know what is 10.20.76.128?

Comment: It is CGNAT (not a public IP). You may have to add a static (public) IP to your contract if they provide. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Does it means that I can never make my machine public with this connection?I cannot afford static IP because it is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FedonKadifeli, mentioned that I have a CGNAT.To make my server public I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1258093/set-up-a-web-server-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat) used ngork.Now I and my friends are able to access my webpage.